# Multiple constructors definitions with same name but different signatures (C++)

Tags: c++, constructor

With the following code, I keep getting error C2535 when I compile. It's complaining that a member function already defined or declared.

### Rationnel.h

```
...
class Rationnel
{   
public:
Rationnel(int); //Constructor
Rationnel(int,int); //Constructor
void add(const Rationnel);
...
```

### Rationnel.cpp

```
...
//Constructor
Rationnel::Rationnel(int n = 1)
{
    numerateur = n;
    denominateur = 1;
}

//Constructor
Rationnel::Rationnel(int n = 1, int d = 1)
{
    numerateur = n;
    denominateur = d;
}
...
```

Any idea what could be causing the error?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can't have both with default arguments. If I call the constructor `Rationnel r;` Which one the compiler should choose?

Comment: You should specify what is the C2535 error in your post.

Comment: The error is: Error 1 error C2535: 'void Rationnel::__dflt_ctor_closure(void)' : member function already defined or declared

Comment: This sounds rather like a compiler error than anything else. Your declarations of those constructors aren't in any way conflicting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write Rationnel (5), how do you know which one of the following will be called ? Both can be used so an error occurs.

```
Rationnel::Rationnel(int n = 1)
Rationnel::Rationnel(int n = 1, int d = 1)
```

Comment: @PuRe_ChAoS12 - In addition to having the most annoying name I've ever had to type, you could achieve the same effect by simply taking out the `Rationnel::Rationell(int)` version.

Comment: Thanks Chris Lutz, this helped me alot as well.